# How to represent a Galois Field with polynomials

Tags: finite-fields, cryptography, galois-representations

I'm given the task of representing a galois field, specifically $GF(107^2)$, by polynomials modulo a irreducible polynomial (which I'm given) in $Z_{107}[x]$. I'm confused on how I'm supposed to go about this, can anyone give me a hint?

Is my solution to generate all possible elements and perform polynomial division on all of them?

I honestly have no idea where to start. A computer is said to be needed to help solve this.

Comment: If $a$ is not a square $\bmod p$ then $\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2-a)$ is a field. Since $107\equiv 3\bmod 4$ you can take $a=$...

Comment: It’s hard to know what is intended by the expression “represent a field”. Each element is well represented by a linear expression $a+b\sqrt?$, as @reuns says. I doubt very much that anybody was asking you to write out a multiplication table, though finding a primitive root (generator of the cyclic group of nonzero elements) in $\Bbb F_{107^2}$ would probably not be too hard. This would allow you to write out a table for the finite logarithm appropriate to this situation. This would almost certainly necessitate a computer.

Comment: In fact, using a relatively incompetent symbolic-computation package, I found a primitive root on my first guess.

Comment: @Lubin What package are you using, if I may ask? I've been trying to find a package that will do the computations I need, but (for Python at least), I can only find packages that do binary fields.

Comment: Try Sage. It's pure Python and has all the facilities.

Comment: This is a vexed question, @SomeGuy . It’s a crude home-made job I cooked up quite a few years ago, writing in java of all things. Not good for anything that requires a lot of memory, but it will work in (almost) any finitely-generated ring over $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Z_p$ or their fraction-fields. I’m sure you want Sage.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I've already completed the question using Sage. Thank you:)